# Handling hierarchical URIs with Flask-RESTful

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I want to have a RESTful api which looks like this:

```
example.com/teams/
example.com/teams/<team_id>
example.com/teams/<team_id>/players
example.com/teams/<team_id>/players/<player_id>
...
example.com/teams/<team_id>/players/<player_id>/seasons/<season_id>/etc
```

Where each URI can appropriately handle GETs and possibly POSTs.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
class Team(Resource):
    def post(self):
        #Handler for /teams/
    def post(self, team_id):
        #Handler for /teams/team_id
    def post(self, team_id, player_id):
        #Handler for /teams/team_id/players/player_id
```

and using:

```
api.add_resource(Team, '/teams/', 'teams/<team_id>/players/<player_id>')
```

Which won't work because the subsequent POST handlers overwrite the previous.

What is the right way with Flask-RESTful to handle an API where there may be a variable number of variables (variable depth of hierarchy) in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support *method overloading* in that particular way. In your code you are not *overloading* the `post()` function, you are *redefining* it

Basically the last definition of `post()` is what counts, which takes 3 parameters as you can see:

```
class Team(Resource):
    def post(self, team_id, player_id):
        # This is the final definition of post()
        # The definitions above this one do not take effect
```

Otherwise it's pretty easy to get the behavior with a single method that has default values for the parameters:

```
class Team(Resource):
    def post(self, team_id=None, player_id=None):
        if team_id is None and player_id is None:
            # first version
        if team_id is not None and player_id is None:
            # second version 
        if team_id is not None and player_id is not None:
            # third version
```

For your URL, Flask will pass in `None` for the parameter that isn't defined in the URL.

Comment: The problem that I see with this is that it does not distinguish between `teams/<team_id>/players` and `teams/<team_id>`. Any ideas?